# How to change mobiscroll script output format?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, mobiscroll

I am trying to use mobiscroll for height selection so I have two wheels one with feet & other inches but the output in the text box after selection is displayed with a space in the numbers instead I want a dot in it how can I do that? Below is my code which I am using presently..

```
var hei=[ { 'Feet': { 1: '1', 2: '2', 3: '3', 4: '4', 5: '5', 6: '6', 7: '7', 8: '8', 9: '9' }, 'Inches': { 1: '1', 2: '2', 3: '3', 4: '4', 5: '5', 6: '6', 7: '7', 8: '8', 9: '9' , 10: '10', 11: '11', 12: '12' } } ]
$('#hei').scroller({
        theme: 'default',
        display: 'mixed',
        mode: 'scroller',
        wheels: hei,
        height: 40
    });
```

And the Html is

```
<input type="text" name="textinput" id="hei" value="" style="width:50%"  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `formatResult` and `parseValue`

```
formatResult: function(data){
            return data[0] + "." + data[1];            
        },
        parseValue: function(valueText)  {
            if (valueText != "") {        
                return valueText.split(".");
            } else{
                return [1,1];
            }
        }
```

For more info go to [Mobiscroll documentation](http://docs.mobiscroll.com).
Also see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kovlex/FxmgS/9/).